# Integral of an Odd Function on $\Bbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

Given an odd integrable function $\Omega$ on $\Bbb R^n$, i.e. $\Omega \in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$ and $\Omega(-x) = -\Omega(x)$, how do I show that its integral over a symmetric set limited $C$ is zero, ie, if $C = - C$, then
$$\int_{C} \Omega(x)dx = 0.$$
It seems reasonable this assertion, since its true on the real line, but I'm in a little trouble to prove that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiplication by $-1$ gives a regular enough function $g: C \rightarrow C$ to apply the substitution rule:

$$\int_{g(C)} \Omega(x) dx= \int_C \Omega(g(y)) | \det ( g’(y))| dy.$$
Since $g’(y)=g$ because $g$ is linear, and since $g(C)=C$, the above gives
$$\int_{C} \Omega(x) dx =\int_C \Omega(-x) dx = - \int_C \Omega(x) dx.$$
I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One question, this argument holds if I change $C$ for $S^{n-1}$, right?

Comment: I guess so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most natural way to do so would be to establish a symmetric partition $P$ on $C$ such that for each $x_i\in P, -x_i\in P$ and then show that the Darboux sums $$U_{\Omega,P}=\sum_{x_i}M_i1_{C}(x^*_i)\Delta x_i=0$$ for all symmetric partitions, $P$. and $$L_{\Omega,P}=\sum_{x_i}m_i1_C(x^*_i)\Delta x_i=0,$$ Then since $$0=U_{\Omega,P}\geq \int_C\Omega(x)dx\geq L_{\Omega,P}=0$$ We can conclude that $\int_C\Omega(x)dx=0$

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer a different basic approach in my opinion. You can approximate your function by symmetric simple functions, for which this statement would be simpler to prove. For $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$, define

$$ E_{m,n}:=\{ x\in C: \frac{m-1}{2^n} \leq \Omega(x)\leq \frac{m}{2^n} \} $$

One can see that

$$ \{ x\in C: -\frac{m-1}{2^n} \geq \Omega(x)\geq -\frac{m}{2^n} \}=-E_{m,n}. $$

Define

$$ \Omega_n(x)= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{m-1}{2^n}\cdot\ \mathbf{1}_{E_{m,n}}(x)-\frac{m-1}{2^n}\cdot\ \mathbf{1}_{-E_{m,n}}(x)\Big) .$$

Then $\Omega_n\to\Omega \cdot \mathbf{1}_C$ almost everywhere and $\vert \Omega_n(x)\vert\leq \vert \Omega(x) \vert$, so
$$ \int \Omega_n(x)dx \to \int \Omega(x)\cdot \mathbf{1}_C(x)dx  $$
by the dominated convergence theorem. Since $E_{m,n}$ and $-E_{m,n}$ have the same measure, we conclude that $\int \Omega_n(x)dx \equiv0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Nice, thanks! If I consider now $\Omega$ odd integrable in a symmetric subset $M$ of $\Bbb R^n$, for example $S^{n-1}$, and $\sigma$ the measure in $M$ induced by the  Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb R^n$, is it possible to have the same conclusion 
$$\int_M \Omega(x) d\sigma(x) = 0 \;\;\; ?$$

Comment: I think that the answer would by yes, since for $E\subseteq S^{n-1}$, the measure of $(-E)\subseteq S^{n-1}$ should be the same.. But you should verify against the definition of an induced measure whether the approximation satisfies the same property.

Comment: I see... porbably this argument work here, I'll check it latter.  One onther thing is that, in this case, if I argue like @M. Van, how do I deal with changing of variables, for example, in $S^{n-1}$?